# How to update fields on import Django?

Tags: django, import, django-import-export

I need to update fields on import for ManyToMany bulk editing.
When importing, now I can only add products, because when I try to add already existing fields, I get a message about already existing IDs.
How can I update products using import?

`admin.py`

```
class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Part

class PartAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ProductResource
    filter_horizontal = ('analog',)

admin.site.register(Part, PartAdmin)
```

`models.py`

```
class Part(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField('Производитель', max_length=100)
    number = models.CharField('Артикул', max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField('Комментарий', blank=True, max_length=5000)
    analog = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='AnalogParts')
    images = models.FileField('Главное изображение', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images0 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images1 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images2 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.brand + " " + self.number + " " + self.name)
        return self.name
```

Comment: Share the related process you have created, please. Model itself does not expose much.

Comment: @NixonSparrow don't quite understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

from import_export.admin import ImportExportActionModelAdmin
from import_export import resources
from import_export import fields
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget

class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):
    #category = fields.Field(column_name='Артикул', attribute='number')

    class Meta:
        model = Part
        import_id_field = 'number'
        import_id_fields = ('number',)

    def skip_row(self, instance, original):
        original_id_value = getattr(original, self._meta.import_id_field)
        instance_id_value = getattr(instance, self._meta.import_id_field)
        if original_id_value != instance_id_value:
            return True
        if not self._meta.skip_unchanged:
            return False
        for field in self.get_fields():
            try:
                if list(field.get_value(instance).all()) != list(field.get_value(original).all()):
                    return False
            except AttributeError:
                if field.get_value(instance) != field.get_value(original):
                    return False
        return True

admin.site.register(Kits)

class PartAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ProductResource
    filter_horizontal = ('analog',)

admin.site.register(Part, PartAdmin)



#class PartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
#    filter_horizontal = ('analog',)

#admin.site.register(Part, PartAdmin)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.